# Unable to run published asp application in windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-7

I have developed one web application and trying to deploy in one machine which is having windows 7. In that I have installed IIS with asp,asp.net etc. Then I copied my published folder to the root location of windows7 machine. Then in IIS manager i converted to Application. While browsing in IE it is loading a blank page with tittle 'Yahoo DNS error handler'. If i run in Firefox it is loading page could not connect error giving.

Can any one tell me how i can solve this problem?

Comment: Can you browse to the root of the IIS server, like http://localhost/ or similar? That yahoo error seems to be coming from a stupid addon or malware.

Comment: some things to check, make sure the firewall is open, make sure the application is started and make sure the bindings on the applications are setup.

Comment: @fejesjoco while loding localhost also same problem is there.

Comment: @SmithMart how to see application is started and make sure the bindings on the applications are setup.?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply! busy weekend :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought i'd write this in an answer for better formatting.

Open IIS, on the left side you will see the list of applications
Right click your application and click Edit Bindings
In here pick the IP Address you wish that application to listen on and the port number, normally 80

you also put the domain, but if you wish all traffic to go to this application then you can leave this field blank.

A good link:
http://www.iisunderground.com/add-a-new-website-iis-7-5/